# Find $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x-1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+(x-1)^2}}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Find $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x-1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+(x-1)^2}}$

---

I tried to solve it by using the property $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$
Let $I=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{(x-1)dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+(x-1)^2}}$
$I=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{(2-x)dx}{(3-x)^2\sqrt{(3-x)^2+(2-x)^2}}$
But this does not seem to work here.I am stuck.What should i do?

Comment: substitute $ x=sin^2(\theta)$

Comment: $\sin^2\theta$ cannot be equal to $2$,i think this substitution will not work.@Boris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First write $$x - 1 = x(2x - 1) - (2x^2 - 2x + 1).$$  Then our integrand becomes:  $$\frac{x-1}{x^2 \sqrt{2x^2 - 2x + 1}} = \frac{2x-1}{x\sqrt{2x^2 - 2x + 1}} - \frac{\sqrt{2x^2 - 2x + 1}}{x^2}.$$  Now with the choice $$u = \sqrt{2x^2 - 2x + 1}, \quad v = \frac{1}{x},$$ we have $$u' = \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}}, \quad v' = -\frac{1}{x^2},$$ hence the integrand is of the form $$u'v + uv' = (uv)'.$$  It immediately follows that an antiderivative is $$\int \frac{x-1}{x^2\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}} \, dx = uv + C = \frac{\sqrt{2x^2 - 2x + 1}}{x} + C.$$  The rest is straightforward.

Comment: Unique approach +1,how does splitting $x-1$ in that way click to you.@heropup

Comment: The idea is to try to see if the integrand is amenable to being written in the form of a product rule.  In order to do this, we try to write it as the sum/difference of two terms.  This suggests trying to "pull out" of the numerator the quadratic polynomial that occurs in the square root, to see if its derivative is remaining; i.e., note that $(2x^2 - 2x + 1)' = 2(2x-1)$, which suggests such a trick may work.

Answer (score 3):

First step is put $x = u+\dfrac{1}{2}\Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+(x-1)^2}=\sqrt{\left(u+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(u-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{2u^2+\dfrac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{u^2+\dfrac{1}{4}}$. Second step is to put $u =\dfrac{1}{2}\tan \theta$. I think we can go further at this point.

Comment: Using the symetry as you did leads to a small marvel ! Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Its fun to be able to use some symmetry in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you write the integral as $$I=\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x}}{x^2\sqrt{1+(1-\frac{1}{x})^2}}$$  now put $1-\frac{1}{x}=y$